# array operation in fortran

Tags: fortran

I am writing a code with a lot of 2D arrays and manipulation of them. I would like the code to be as concise as possible, for that I would like to use as many 'implicit' operation on array as possible but I don't really know how to write them for 2D arrays.
For axample:

```
DO  J=1,N
   DO  I=1,M
    A(I,J)=B(J)*A(I,J)
   ENDDO
ENDDO
```

become easily:

```
DO  J=1,N
 A(:,J)=B(J)*A(:,J)
ENDDO
```

Is there a way to reduce also the loop J?

Thanks

Comment: No, not really, at least as far as I can think. I guess you could package up the 2D arrays in a derived type and define a suitable multiplication operation on the type, but IMO the above code is nice and short and clear, and I can't see any problem with it.

Comment: You may be able to find some ideas in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59269264/3157076) and its answers, but I'd also be tempted to just leave it as it is.

Comment: As the author of one of the answers to the question @francescalus points us towards, I'll just re-iterate: while it's fun to craft one-liners to implement whole-array operations in modern Fortran, it's rare to be able to write a one-liner that's as fast as explicit loops, and almost always tends towards reduced readability.  And don't forget that the person most likely to be reading the code in 3 month's time and trying to figure out what the 'cunning' one-liner actually does is the code's author.

Comment: You could bury the existing two do loops into a separate library function and have the name of the function provide the "concise" aspect. Maybe COL_MULT in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one-line solution can be achieved by using `FORALL`:

```
FORALL(J=1:N) A(:,J) = B(J)*A(:,J)
```

Note that `FORALL` is deprecated in the most recent versions of the standard, but as far as I know, that is the only way you can perform that operation as a single line of code.

Comment: True. But due to it being deprecated forall is really best totally avoided in any new code.

Comment: Forall was mostly a failure and often is problematic to optimize.

Comment: Basically, if you write `DO  J=1,N; A(:,J)=B(J)*A(:,J); ENDDO` it looks almost the same and is also on one line... Differences in readability are arguable.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - It would be nice to address this `FORALL` vs `DO CONCURRENT` or others behavior: I've been doing some tests with gfortran and have never found `FORALL` to be any slower (perhaps I'll put them together into another thread). I'm evidently on the wrong side of history and will have to surrender to all this verbosity, but I really do like the compact array/matrix syntax that Fortran had started to achieve since Fortran 90/95: it could've become the fastest compiled language _and_ with a clear Matlab/Python-like syntax.

Answer (score 1):

For brevity and clarity, you could wrap these operations in a **derived type**. I wrote a minimal example which is not so concise because I need to initialise the objects, but once this initialisation is done, manipulating your arrays becomes very concise and elegant.

I stored in `arrays_module.f90` a derived type `arrays2d_T` which can hold the array coefficients, plus useful information (number of rows and columns). This type contains procedures for initialisation, and the operation you are trying to perform.

```
module arrays_module

implicit none

integer, parameter :: dp = kind(0.d0) !double precision definition

 type :: arrays2d_T
   real(kind=dp), allocatable :: dat(:,:)
   integer :: nRow, nCol     
  contains
   procedure :: kindOfMultiply => array_kindOfMuliply_vec
   procedure :: init           => initialize_with_an_allocatable
 end type

 contains

 subroutine initialize_with_an_allocatable(self, source_dat, nRow, nCol)
   class(arrays2d_t), intent(inOut) :: self
   real(kind=dp), allocatable, intent(in) :: source_dat(:,:)
   integer, intent(in) :: nRow, nCol
   allocate (self%dat(nRow, nCol), source=source_dat)
   self%nRow = nRow
   self%nCol = nCol
 end subroutine

 subroutine array_kindOfMuliply_vec(self, vec)
   class(arrays2d_t), intent(inOut) :: self
   real(kind=dp), allocatable, intent(in) :: vec(:)
   integer :: iRow, jCol
   do jCol = 1, self%nCol
   do iRow = 1, self%nRow
      self%dat(iRow, jCol) = vec(jCol)*self%dat(iRow, jCol)
   end do
   end do
 end subroutine

end module arrays_module
```

Then, in `main.f90`, I check the behaviour of this multiplication on a simple example:

```
program main
use arrays_module
implicit none

type(arrays2d_T) :: A
real(kind=dp), allocatable :: B(:)

! auxilliary variables that are only useful for initialization
real(kind=dp), allocatable :: Aux_array(:,:)
integer :: M = 3
integer :: N = 2

! initialise the 2d array
allocate(Aux_array(M,N))
Aux_array(:,1) = [2._dp, -1.4_dp, 0.3_dp]
Aux_array(:,2) = [4._dp, -3.4_dp, 2.3_dp]
call A%init(aux_array, M, N)

! initialise vector
allocate (B(N))
B = [0.3_dp, -2._dp]

! compute the product
call A%kindOfMultiply(B)

print *, A%dat(:,1)
print *, A%dat(:,2)
end program main
```

Compilation can be as simple as `gfortran -c arrays_module.f90 && gfortran -c main.f90 && gfortran -o main.out main.o arrays_module.o`

Once this object-oriented machinery exists, `call A%kindOfMultiply(B)` is much clearer than a `FORALL` approach (and much less error prone).

Comment: The modern way to `initialize_with_an_allocatable` is to write `allocate (self%dat, source=source_dat)` or something similar but syntactically correct.  The subroutine above isn't really needed.

Comment: And the modern way to write @HighPerformanceMark's `allocate(self%dat, source=source_dat)` is `self%dat=source_dat`.  (I actually find the do construct much clearer than even `call A%kindOfMultiply(B)`, but it's good to see alternatives.)

Comment: Thank you @HighPerformanceMark , I added your suggestion to the code. I used to be a little worried with these modern allocation statements, as some of them (I don't remember which one unfortunately) were not supported by my compiler, back when I first tried them. I agree that the initialization subroutine essentially substitutes 1 line of code instead of 3. IMHO, it does make a difference when the complexity of the main code increases: it is easier to focus on the flow of abstract manipulations, as book-keeping is (ever so slightly) reduced. I can't argue that it is a matter of taste though.

Comment: @francescalus: well, yes, and d'ohhhh.

Comment: @francescalus: does your suggestion belong to the fortran 2003 standard, or to a more recent standard? Any possible pitfall with (modern) compilers? I was warned that compilers' support was lagging behind the standard.

Comment: Automatic allocation of non-polymorphic arrays on intrinsic assignment is a F2003 feature (for polymorphic it's F2008) and is well supported now (even if not the default behaviour for some compiler - with recent Intel compilers it is the default now).  Support for polymorphic intrinsic assignment is indeed more troublesome, but so sourced allocation also can be.

Comment: @francescalus thank you for the detailled explanations.

Answer (score 1):

No one has mentioned `do concurrent` construct here, which has *the potential* to automatically parallelize and speed up your code,

```
do concurrent(j=1:n); A(:,j)=B(j)*A(:,j); end do
```